# Gradle build errors when importing "tree-view-list-android"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import tree-view-android [link](https://github.com/kedzie/tree-view-list-android) as a new project to use in conjunction with another project. However when I import I get this build error:

```
Error:(21, 0) Failed to apply plugin [id 'ameba-project-release']
```

I used the gradle wrapper for configuration

Here is the build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath ('com.apphance.ameba:Ameba:0.99.4.1-SNAPSHOT')
}
}

apply plugin: 'ameba-project-configuration'
apply plugin: 'ameba-mercurial'
//apply plugin: 'ameba-git'
apply plugin: 'ameba-android-build'
apply plugin: 'ameba-project-release'
apply plugin: 'ameba-android-release'
//apply plugin: 'ameba-android-apphance'
apply plugin: 'ameba-android-analysis' 
//apply plugin: 'ameba-android-test'
//apply plugin: 'ameba-android-jarlibrary'
apply from: 'http://dev.polidea.pl/ext/Ameba/polidea_conventions.gradle'
```

I have tried to change the dependancies to a more updated snapshot and modified the maven but that didn't work.

Comment: I've successfully added the library in Eclipse, my project worked and then I imported Eclipse Project in Android Studio and after few small issues everything works fine. Yeah, I know it's not a solution. I've just added a comment as a curiosity.